# react-router does not navigate to desired the route after an async operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I was working on a project when it turned out that when I dispatched an action and tried to navigate to the /home route after making an async call to my api and using the await keyword to wait for my response , it was not functioning.

I reproduce the problem in a simple react app [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-gwen-r0kgqd?file=/src/component/Forms.jsx)

The issue with the following code is that it does not navigate to the home route when isLogged is true.

app.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./component/Home";
import Login from "./component/Login";

export default function App() {
  const { isLogged } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  console.log("rendered");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={isLogged ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Forms from "./Forms";

const Login = () => {
  const [openform, setOpenForm] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="login">
      {openform && <Forms />}
      {!openform && (
        <button onClick={() => setOpenForm(!openform)}>
          click to open Form
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Forms.jsx

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { setIsLogged } from "../store/authSlice";
const Forms = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  var goToHome = () => {
    dispatch(setIsLogged(true));
    navigate("/home");
  };
  const submit = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("finished");
      goToHome();//It works if I call the goToHome method straight without using the timeout.
    }, 2000);
  };
  return (
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" />
      <button onClick={submit}>click to login</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Forms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not preventing the default form action from occurring, resulting in the page reloading and the entire React app remounting. Consume the `onSubmit` event object and call `preventDefault` on it.

Example:

```
const Forms = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goToHome = () => {
    dispatch(setIsLogged(true));
    navigate("/home");
  };

  const submit = (e) => { // <-- consume onSubmit event object
    e.preventDefault();   // <-- prevent default form action
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      goToHome();
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" />
      <button onClick={submit}>click to login</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```